# Vector iterator not deferencable in Visual Studio

Tags: c++

> when calling next.  next function is not dereferencable in Visual Studio 2015. run time error

```
class Vector2D {
public:
    Vector2D(vector<vector<int>>& vec2d) {
        it = vec2d.begin();
        endit = vec2d.end();
    }

    int next() {

        return (*it)[j++];
    }

    bool hasNext() {
        while (it != endit && j == (*it).size())
            it++, j = 0;
        return it != endit;
    }
    vector<vector<int>>::iterator it, endit;
    int j;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`int j;` - you forgot to initialize it and `next()` is looking for some garbage memory address and crashing.

Also `hasNext()` never initialize `j` because `it != endit && j == (*it).size()` is always false, since `j` is still garbage.

Fix is simple - initialize `int j` in constructor or via in-place initialization like `int j { 0 };`

Comment: Even thought I initialized it int the constructor with this->j = 0; its the same error. This only happens in Visual Studio

Comment: where you initialized it?